# Nestjs session didn't set in browser cookie

Tags: node.js, session, nestjs

**I use nestjs make a simple session base auth, and setting session like below.

When I use postman to test is work,but use browser to login that the sessionId didn't set in browser cookie**

```js
    async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const configService = app.get<ConfigService>(ConfigService);
  const sessionSecret = configService.get('SESSION_SECRET');
  const PORT = configService.get('PORT');
  app.enableCors();

  app.use(
    session({
      secret: sessionSecret,
      resave: false,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 60 * 60 * 1000,
      },
    }),
  );

  await app.listen(PORT, () =>
    console.log(`server is listen on http://localhost:${PORT}`),
  );
}
```

**login controller as below:**

```js
  @Post('/login')
  async login(@Body() loginDto: loginDto, @Session() session: SessionData) {
    const foundUser = await this.authService.login(loginDto);

    const { id, name, role, department, email, points, pwdChanged } = foundUser;

    console.log(`user ${name} login successfully`);

    session.user = {
      id,
      name,
      email,
      role,
      department,
      points,
    };

    return {};
  }
```

**got response as below:**
[image]

**cookie set nothing**
[image]

Comment: Did you find the issue? Running into the same behaviour now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a little miss understanding of the session and cookies on the server side.

Cookies are pieces of data that will generate by the server and will save on the client side each time client sends a request, the server will receive the cookie and extract data from it.

The session is a mechanism to store data on the server side based on user interaction. The server will send an id to the client and on each request server will find the data, based on the client id. In your case when the user hits the login endpoint server will keep the data in the server and sets an id which is `connect.sid` so you need another endpoint to retrieve the user info:

```
  @Post('/login')
  async login(@Session() session: Record<string, any>) {
    session.user = {
      id: 69,
      name: 'mohsen',
      email: 'mohsenmahoski@gmail.com',
      role: 'Admin',
      department: 'development',
      points: 'nothing',
    };

    return 'Session set successfully';
  }

  @Get('/me')
  async me(@Session() session: Record<string, any>) {
    const user = session.user;
    return user;
  }
```

Comment: You're not addressing the question, it's clear that he knows how to set a session and he's doing it correctly but his issue is that nestJs doesn't send the cookie back to his browser (the SESSIONID cookie) which is a valid poorly documented issue with nestJs